# Clarification needed about a theorem on strings on an alphabet

Tags: induction, proof-explanation

[image]In the attached lecture slides, the proof by induction is used to establish that $uv=vu$ implies that both $v$ and $u$ are powers of the same string.

I am attempting to follow this in terms of a rigorous induction proof, but I feel like this example skips a few details.
As the proof says, we can assume $|u| + |v| = n$.

Case 1 ($|u| = |v|$): The slide states, “The statement is true.”  Why is this true? Are we assuming this is true because it is an induction hypothesis, or is a statement required to prove this?  If required to prove this, surely there would have to be some evidence for that claim?

Case 2 ($|u| < |v|$ or $|v| < |u|$):
If we have $v = uw$, and $uv = vu$, we can plug $uw$ in for $v$ to get $uuw = uwu$, which clearly implies that $uw = wu$
Since $v = uw$, it is clear that $|w| < |v|$.

Which means that $|u| + |w| < |u| + |v|$.

My confusion comes in at this point, because I am unsure how this inequality confirms the induction hypothesis.  If someone could perhaps clarify how this means that they are powers of the same string, that would be greatly helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, if $|u|=|v|$ say they each had length $L$.  Then the first $L$ letters of $uv$ must be the same as the first $L$ letters of $vu$.  Thus...

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order for it to be precise and concise (an aim that is sometimes difficult to achieve) ; its "appeal" should be improved (I have added "alphabet" because there is another meaning for "strings").

Comment: As for the second case: if $uw=wu$ and $|u|+|w|\lt n$, then by the induction hypothesis we have that $u$ and $w$ are powers of the same string; that is, $u=z^i$, $w=z^j$ for some string $z$. Now, $v=uw$; can you write $v$ in terms of $z$?